# Getting "Updated" Error When Trying to Set Extended Field Value for INRegister

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to set an extended field value for INRegister after I create and insert a new INKitRegister object into the KitAssemblyEntry graph. I understand that the INKitRegister, on save, has a method which creates the INRegister that is stored in the database for the kit. After the save, I have code that I want to execute that would set the extension field I added to the INRegister data table. When this code executes, I get the following error:

> Error #78: Another process has updated the 'INRegister' record. Your changes will be lost.

I'm not sure why since I execute this edit after the data table entry is completed.

Here is my code:

```
        ...//Code to create component children

        INKitRegister kitHeader = new INKitRegister
        {
            //set header fields
        };

        //I also have this extended field on the INKitRegister DAC
        INKitRegisterExt kitHeaderExt = PXCache<INKitRegister>.GetExtension<INKitRegisterExt>(kitHeader);
        kitHeaderExt.UsrWOID = CurrentDocument.Current.Id;

        INTranSplit kitParentAssembly = new INTranSplit
        {
            //Making INTranSplit entry for kit
        };

        ...
        //Do I need to get the graph's extension? set register view? do I need to get kitHeader's inserted refNbr and forward that to function to set woid?
        KitAssemblyEntry graphKAE = PXGraph.CreateInstance<KitAssemblyEntry>();
        graphKAE.Document.Insert(kitHeader);
        graphKAE.Document.Current.KitRevisionID = "1";
        graphKAE.Actions.PressSave();

        foreach (INComponentTran ch in kitChildren)
        {
            ch.RefNbr = kitHeader.RefNbr;
            graphKAE.Components.Insert(ch);
        }

        graphKAE.Actions.PressSave();

        //Code in which I get the newly created INRegister and set the extended field.
        string refNbr = graphKAE.Document.Current.RefNbr;
        INRegister reg = PXSelect<INRegister, Where<INRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<INRegister.refNbr>>, And<INRegister.docType, Equal<Required<INRegister.docType>>>>>
            .Select(this, refNbr, "P");
        INRegisterExt regExt = PXCache<INRegister>.GetExtension<INRegisterExt>(reg);
        regExt.UsrWOID = CurrentDocument.Current.Id;

        INRegisters.Update(reg);        

        this.Actions.PressSave();


        PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(graphKAE, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.Popup);
```

Any suggestions? I tried placing the code in a KitAssemblyEntry_Extension class under INKitRegister_RowPersisting and INKitRegister_RowUpdating. I've also looked into possibly executing the update when the popup window closes, but I do not know how to do that. Any help is welcome to point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indicates the record you have is not the latest as it exists in the database. Try using PXSelectReadonly in place of PXSelect to get your INRegister (reg) object.

I assume it is the line "INRegisters.Update(reg);" then save that is failing?

I would also try to use the kit graph to update the INRegister and select the inregister. Try changing this one section...

```
//Code in which I get the newly created INRegister and set the extended field.
string refNbr = graphKAE.Document.Current.RefNbr;
INRegister reg = PXSelectReadOnly<INRegister, 
    Where<INRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<INRegister.refNbr>>, 
    And<INRegister.docType, Equal<Required<INRegister.docType>>>>>
    .Select(graphKAE, refNbr, "P");
INRegisterExt regExt = PXCache<INRegister>.GetExtension<INRegisterExt>(reg);
regExt.UsrWOID = CurrentDocument.Current.Id;

graphKAE.Caches[typeof(INRegister)].PersistUpdated(graphKAE.Caches[typeof(INRegister)].Update(reg));
```

Comment: Changed the code to: string refNbr = graphKAE.Document.Current.RefNbr;
            INRegister reg = PXSelectReadonly<INRegister, Where<INRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<INRegister.refNbr>>, And<INRegister.docType, Equal<Required<INRegister.docType>>>>>
                .Select(this, refNbr, "P");
            INRegisterExt regExt = PXCache<INRegister>.GetExtension<INRegisterExt>(reg);
            regExt.UsrWOID = CurrentDocument.Current.Id;

            INRegisters.Update(reg);        And am still getting the same error. Should I change it somewhere else?

Comment: To add to that, I did try using PXSelectReadonly<INRegister> Registers when creating the view in the KitAssemblyEntry. That failed to work there as well, but also was the only way I could get the Registers view to populate. Using just PXSelect<> failed and Registers would always be null.

Comment: updated answer. i try to keep the persists of data to a single graph. When you try to persist data in multiple graphs and its of the same DACs things can get a little weird. One common issue i would assume would be the error you receive as graph 1 updates the table and then graph 2 tries and update but doesnt have the latest data from the update of graph 1 (thus the error)

Comment: That last edit did it. I don't think I'd ever even come close to coming up with that sort of solution. Where/how did you learn to do that? I mean I get what you are doing, but I never seen PersistUpdated before.

Comment: Typically you want to lets all the persists of data be performed when the entire graph Persist (or PressSave) gets called. Sometimes it makes sense to specifically persist a single row and/or when you don't have a data view defined. Glad that worked. With the code i work with i have had a lot of exposure to extending and creating custom graphs. Sometimes just peaking through the included source code or looking at new code changes in Acumatica helps to reveal different calls that might come in handy someday.